# Finding lines containing '@' sign

Tags: bash, awk

Is there possibility to use awk to find email adresses?
I got some file with text like

```
www.examplesite1.com
login=user1
www.gmail.com
login=freeuser@gmail.com
```

to find login lines I'm using

```
awk '/user=*/' file.txt
```

Don't know how to find line which contains `'@'`

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: really? `awk '/@/' file.txt`

Comment: rofl. i was trying with something like /*@*/. Ofc i didn't check the most logical one. Thanks :)

Comment: awk uses regex inside `//` not glob.

Comment: @uxez You need to do some googling on how to use regexps. `*@*` means a literal `*` character followed by zero or more repetitions of the `@` character and `user=*` means `user` followed by zero or more repetitions of `=`. You probably just meant `user=` for the latter (or more likely `login=`).

Answer (score 2):

For finding the lines containing `@` symbol.

```
awk '/@/' file.txt
```

For finding the lines startswith `login` and contain `@` in it's value.

```
awk '/^login=.+@.+/' file.txt
```

And to get the text after `=`

```
$ awk '/^login=.+@.+/{sub(/^login=/, ""); print}' file
freeuser@gmail.com
```

Comment: Ok. that helps me a lot. But what if i have not only 'login=', but  ' username= ' or ' user= ' . Is there more elastic command ( i mean everything before '=' ) ?

Comment: `awk '/.*=.+@.+/{sub(/^[^=]+=/, ''); print}' file`

Comment: sorry, use double quotes, `awk '/.*=.+@.+/{sub(/^[^=]+=/, ""); print}' file`